# specifying the "editable" attribute in two different views

Tags: odoo

i have a model that defined a nomenclator, it have only one field :

```
'name': fields.char('Name',size = 50,required = True),
```

and its view is as follow:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_df_t_r_m_resource_type_tree">
    <field name="name">df.t.r.m.resource.type.tree</field>
    <field name="model">df.t.r.m.resource.type</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Types" editable="bottom">
            <field name="name" select = "1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_df_t_r_m_resource_type_form">
    <field name="res_model">df.t.r.m.resource.type</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
</record>
```

I use this view to create types of product, but when i make a many2one field that reference the nomencaltor mode in other view and press the "Search" options i cant select the item because the editable property defined in the original view mess with the behavior i want

So: any ideas about how i can define the "editable" property in diferents views

PD: I tried to use this:

```
<field name="type_id" >
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>                    
            </tree>
          </field>
```

but i dont know how to specify the "editable" property

Comment: can you give us the code for the many2one field and its xml representation (extended view i guess)?

Comment: the xml representation is in PD and many2one field as follow 'type_id': fields.many2one('df.t.r.m.resource.type','Type',required = True),